# Bind SELECT Element with an Array of objects using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to populate a SELECT dropdown list with an array of objects using JavaScript and then display properties of that object based on the option selection. So far I have been able to populate the dropdown, however I can't seem to get the output correctly, as it only selects the last value in the for loop and hence only outputs the last object, for each selection. I thought this might be a closure issue, but I have gone through a lot closure solutions and none seem to work. How can I get each option selection to display the right object properties?

```
<html>

<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="populateSelect()" value="Click to Populate SELECT" />

    <!--The SELECT element.-->
    <select id="sel" onchange="show()">
        <option value="">-- Select --</option>
    </select>

    <p id="msg"></p>
</body>

<script>
  // THE ARRAY.
    var birds = [
            {ID: 001, Bird_Name: "Eurasian Collared-Dove"},
            {ID: 002, Bird_Name: "Bald Eagle"},
            {ID: 003, Bird_Name: "Cooper's Hawk"},
        ];

    function populateSelect() {
        var ele = document.getElementById('sel');
        for (var i = 0; i < birds.length; i++) {
            // POPULATE SELECT ELEMENT WITH JSON.
            ele.innerHTML = ele.innerHTML +
                '<option>' + birds[i]['Bird_Name'] + '</option>';
        }
    }

    function show() {
        // GET THE SELECTED VALUE FROM <select> ELEMENT AND SHOW IT.
        var msg = document.getElementById('msg');
        for (var i = 0; i < birds.length; i++)
        {
            msg.innerHTML = birds[i].ID + " " + birds[i].Bird_Name;
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're successful at populating it, then you don't need another loop to find the selected value. You can use `e.value` or if you want the text of the select, `e.text`. Parse `e` as a parameter in your `onchange`, since you're doing it inline, rather than using an eventlistener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `value` for the options and pass that value into your event handler function. Then compare selected value to the elements in array as well as set a default if no value selected

```js
var birds = [
            {ID: 001, Bird_Name: "Eurasian Collared-Dove"},
            {ID: 002, Bird_Name: "Bald Eagle"},
            {ID: 003, Bird_Name: "Cooper's Hawk"},
        ];


function populateSelect() {
  var ele = document.getElementById('sel');
  birds.forEach(function(b) {
    ele.innerHTML += '<option value="' + b.ID + '">' + b['Bird_Name'] + '</option>';
  })

}

function show(id) {
  // GET THE SELECTED VALUE FROM <select> ELEMENT AND SHOW IT.
  var msg = document.getElementById('msg');
  if (!id) {
    msg.innerHTML = 'None selected';

  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < birds.length; i++) {
      if (Number(id) === birds[i].ID) {
        msg.innerHTML = birds[i].ID + " " + birds[i].Bird_Name;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

populateSelect()
```

```html
<select id="sel" onchange="show(this.value)">
  <option value="">-- Select --</option>
</select>

<p id="msg"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the value attribute in  tag, also as one of the comment mentions you can make use of the events too.

```js
// THE ARRAY.
var birds = [{
    ID: 001,
    Bird_Name: "Eurasian Collared-Dove"
  },
  {
    ID: 002,
    Bird_Name: "Bald Eagle"
  },
  {
    ID: 003,
    Bird_Name: "Cooper's Hawk"
  },
];

var select = document.getElementById('sel');

function populateSelect() {
  for (var i = 0; i < birds.length; i++) {
    // POPULATE SELECT ELEMENT WITH JSON.
    // add the value attribute in option as the id of bird
    select.innerHTML = select.innerHTML +
      '<option value=' + birds[i].ID + '>' + birds[i]['Bird_Name'] + '</option>';
  }
}

function show() {
  // GET THE SELECTED VALUE FROM <select> ELEMENT AND SHOW IT.
  var msg = document.getElementById('msg');
  // find the bird with the selected id
  let selectedBird = birds.find(bird => bird.ID == select.value);
  // display the info
  msg.innerHTML = selectedBird.ID + " " + selectedBird.Bird_Name;

}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input type="button" onclick="populateSelect()" value="Click to Populate SELECT" />

  <!--The SELECT element.-->
  <select id="sel" onchange="show()">
    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
  </select>

  <p id="msg"></p>
</body>

</html>
```